# How to solve this problem using set theory?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$36$ students took English and Math test. $25$ passed English, and $28$ passed Math. $20$ passed both subjects.

**a.** How many students failed both subject?
**b.** How many students passed english only?
**c.** How many students passed math only?

Comment: What does the question has to do with set theory?

Comment: This is a job for... [Inclusion-Exclusion Man!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 3):

If $E$ is the set of the students that passed English and $M$ are those that passed Math then you have:

$|E|=25$, $|M|=28$, $|E\cap M|=20$

From the formula

$$|E\cup M|=|E|+|M|-|E\cap M|$$

you get that $|E\cup M|=33$, which means that 33 students passed at least one subject.

I guess you can go on from here...

If you prefer diagrams instead of formulas, you can try to draw something like the diagrams shown here (just with different numbers): [Venn Diagrams: Exercises](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/venndiag4.htm) (Purplemath). To prevent the link rot, here is also [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20180725010222/http://www.purplemath.com/modules/venndiag4.htm).

Perhaps I should have also added the link to the Wikipedia article [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: You may want to change the URLs..

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $S$ the set of all students, by $E$ the set of all students that passed English and by $M$ the set of all students that passed Math. Then what you know is: $|S|=36$, $|E|=25$, $|M|=28$ and $|E\cap M|=20$. Then what you are looking for is:
**a.** $|(S\setminus E)\cap (S\setminus M)|=$
**b.** $|E\setminus M|=$
**c.** $|M\setminus E|=$
So you can use De Morgan's laws and Martin Sleziak's answer from here on to solve...

Answer (score 0):

Let $e$ be the number of students who passed English but not math,
$m$ the number of students who passed math but not English,
$a$ the number of students who passed both tests,
$z$ the number of students who passed neither test.

$$36=e+m+a+z$$
$$25=e+a$$
$$28=m+a$$
$$20=a$$

$4$ equations in $4$ unknowns!

Spoiler:
$$a=20$$
$$e=(e+a)-a=25-20=5$$
$$m=(m+a)-a=28-20=8$$
$$e+m+a+z=36$$
$$5+8+20+z=36$$
$$33+z=36$$
$$z=36-33=3$$